# What's the correct way to make it so that node_load both loads and caches additional, custom data?

Tags: 7, caching, nodes

For example, I'd like node_load to load the path alias of the node, and cache it for future node_load calls (just like node_load caches all of the data, i think). I assume this is done in a module, but I haven't been able to find examples of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook you're after is called [`hook_node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7). I think the example from that page is probably the easiest to understand:

```
function hook_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  $result = db_query('SELECT nid, foo FROM {mytable} WHERE nid IN(:nids)', array(':nids' => array_keys($nodes)));
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $nodes[$record->nid]->foo = $record->foo;
  }
}
```

The example loads some custom data from a table, based on the ids of the nodes passed into the function. It then loops through the query results, and adds the custom data to the relevant node objects.

When you call `node_load()` or `node_load_multiple()` for nodes that haven't been cached yet, your `hook_node_load()` function will be called and the custom data added.

Next time you call those functions for the same nodes your hook won't be called, but the node objects returned from the static cache will already have your custom data attached to them.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I've read elsewhere that hook_node_load will NOT cache your custom data, i.e. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/after-adding-data-to-nodes-using-hook-node-load-will-this-data-be-saved-in-th

Comment: I'm talking about the static page cache, not the persistent database cache. If you want to cache the results of your database call then yes, you'll need to do that yourself. But that's true of absolutely any situation where you use data from a custom database in Drupal. The example in Chapabu's answer from that question is great, if you combine that logic with the above then you'll have persistent and static page caching for your data. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I see, my mistake entirely. Thanks for the clarification. Static page cache is actually what I'm after, so this is perfect.